# Data structure C++ to store a 2-D grid with other details?

Tags: c++, tree, grid, maps

I would like to store a 2d grid,with information about its:

1. its predecessors
2. possible successors

each of them should also store the same: Now I tough I could use a tree,but along with the order of the nodes, I would like to store other details as well(for example lets say weight of the cell,its name blah blah...)

Point is I cant find a tree implementation of trees in STL. I tried using maps,but is there a way to use maps from STL as tree? I'm curious as how to implement them using maps,but not necessarily.

(THIS IS NOT HOMEWORK)

Comment: There isn't an STL implementation of tree, but a `map` is essentially a tree in its implementation to allow for efficient key search. Don't think you can access parent/children information in a map though. So if you want to use `map`s then you probably need to add pointers to your class, but that defeats the purpose I think. However, if your tree is going to be a regular tree, like k-D (each parent has k children), then you can use an integer key and your class as a map, and the integer key can be used to identify the children or parent:

Comment: if the parent's key is `a` then its children will be numbered `ak+1`, `ak+2`, ..., `ak+k`. And if a children has a key equal to `b`, then its parent's key is `floor((b-1)/k)`. In this case, the root is going to have a key of `0`. I hope I did the math correctly :-)

Comment: @triple_r thank you,I got the gist of it,how did you figure out the math btw? :)

Comment: LOL, I did it in my head, but hoping it is correct. You should be able to find the correct math in any book that talks about these structures. If `k` is a power of 2, you should even be able to do the math using some bit-tricks, shifts, ... Numerical Recipes comes to my mind as a book that must have the correct math in it.